# Get ActionBarDrawerToggle from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I have have a MainActivity.java with draweractivity and kind of listener of it

```
toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            FloatingButton.getInstance(context).showFloatingActionButton();
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            FloatingButton.getInstance(context).hideFloatingActionButton();
        }
    };
```

i can access to it only from MainActivity

And also i have 10 fragments. i need to access to this listener from each fragment.

Any ideas how? Thx in advance!

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: @miav i need to hide floating button from the fragment on drawer open. btw, each fragment uses separate buttons

Comment: And all your 10 fragments are part of DrawerLayout that you are using for Activity?

Comment: @MeTechnical all fragments going from MainActivity and they all using this DrawerLayout. but DrawerLayout is in main_activity.xml and all control is going from MainActivity.java

Comment: You could just give all buttons the same id, as long as they are in separate fragments.

Comment: @miav, okay but how to control them from MainActivity?

Comment: `((FloatingButton) findViewById(R.id.button)).hide()` hides `R.id.button` . Fragments views are reachable from activities, as long as the fragment is in there.